# Address Suggestion in Android

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I'm not using AutoCompleteEditText which is suggesting addresses by user inputed keyword, but I'd like to get the most similar suggestion address from my input address.
The reason why I don't use AutoCompleteEditText is that I have to input the incomplete address in EditText and in the next page, I have to show both addresses - 1 is my inputed address and other is suggested complete address.
How to solve this?

Comment: You have to use list of your addresses and TextWatcher to catch user input and search in your list.

Comment: What do you mean the list?

Comment: How can I make the list of all over the world addresses?

Comment: Then use TextWatcher and addTextChangedListener and search your addresses where you wanted with autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid all the handling and show suggestion you can integrate google's autocomplete picker

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

It will handle suggestion by its own for you.